# How to change cell's size dynamically in a custom UICollectionView without implementing collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have created my own layout by subclassing the `UICollectionViewLayout` class, and not the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` one. Hence it seems that I cannot implement the method `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Unfortunately, I may want to change my cell's sizes dynamically. For instance, I have a set a little circular cells around a big cell. When the user exchange a small cell with the big one, I want the little cell to take the location and the size of the big cell, while the big cell would get as small as the little cell and it would take its location. I already managed to do the location exchange (with the `moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` method) but the cell won't change their size.

I understand that the layout is the only responsible for updating item's size, but I can assure that I have tried anything and the cells still don't resize.

Does anyone have an idea of what I could do? I would be very grateful!

Comment: posting some code might help ;)

Comment: Did you call `-invalidateLayout`?